# A regular expression for simple JSON, specific capture groups?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression that will parse:

> {A:\"B\",C:{D:\"E\",F:{G:\"H\",I:\"J\"}}}

Such that the matches come out to:

> {
>
> A:\"B\",
>
> C:
>
> {
>
> D:\"E\",
>
> F:
>
> {
>
> G:\"H\",
>
> I:\"J\"
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }

I have come close except that I have to capture the commas in their own capture groups and not sure how to otherwise. In a programming language I would read until I hit either a comma, open bracket, or close bracket and then push the string, then push the symbol

The closest I have gotten has been:

> ([\[\]{,])([^,\[\]{}]+)|([}\[\],])

Comment: It's true for JSON too: don't parse it with regex, unless it's **very** simple. There are tons of JSON parsers out there, you are better off with them.

Comment: Aye, this isn't for any real production code. You are spot on regarding json parsers, I have many working libs to solve this problem the right way. I was more wondering as an exercise in writing regular expressions;  a self sought curiosity mostly. I still feel like its possible to include the comma as part of the second capture group though...

Comment: It is possible. Somebody wrote one in perl http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=995856 . Others are still trying to understand it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching the comma's and mustaches.
Or the colons and double quotes that are followed by a mustache.
Then add a newline to the matches.

```
/[,{}]|[":](?=[{}])/g
```

Replace with `"$0\\n"`

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/WpVEVH/2)

Comment: ah, look ahead, that was the missing piece I have been needing :) big thanks!